# On mouseover text, title shows extra space in Firefox and not in Chrome

Tags: html

[image]

In Firefox the title show with some extra spaces.

My code in JSP

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address 1</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post some related code also

Comment: please help with showing your code?

Comment: I tried by giving the label in single line and issue got solved. But I can't go and change the same for all my code :-(

Comment: can you post the online link of your page?